What is the name of this horror/thriller about an address book killer?
I'm looking for a movie i watched quite some time ago. At least 10 years. The movie is about a guy somehow obtaining someones address book. He then ends up being fatally injured in a car accident. They try to revive him in the hospital when lightning strikes. He is then somehow absorbed into the world of electricity. He uses his newfound powers in this world to kill everyone in the address book.
Little parts I remember:

He tries killing someone by overheating a microwave
He asks someone to touch the computer screen through chat, trying to kill that person in this manner
A dog is being drowned in the pool by closing the cover


I think film that you are looking for is Ghost in the Machine. Karen Allen was the main actress in that; it was the same year she played the mom in the always classic The Sandlot. The synopsis:

Karl Hochman, a technician in a computer shop, is also "The Address-Book Killer", who obtains the names of his victims from stolen address-books. Terry Munroe and her son Josh come into the store to price software, and a salesman uses Terry's address-book to demonstrate a hand-held scanner. Karl obtains the file, and while driving to Terry's house that night in a heavy electrical storm, his car runs off the road and lands upside down in a cemetery. While Karl is undergoing a CAT scan at the hospital, a surge of lightning courses through the building, and Karl's mind is transformed into electrical energy. Karl uses the electrical grid and computer networks to continue his killing-spree. 

